# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Binary'

Tags: python, pytest

I'm working through http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/05/13/python-oop-tdd-example-part1/#.VxEEfjE2sdQ . I'm working through this iteratively. At this point I have the following Binary class:

```
class Binary:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = str(value)
        if self.value[:2] == '0b':
            print('a binary!')
            self.value= int(self.value, base=2)
        elif self.value[:2] == '0x':
            print('a hex!')
            self.value= int(self.value, base=5)
        else:
            print(self.value)
        return None
```

I'm running through a suite of tests using pytest, including:

```
    def test_binary_init_hex():
        binary = Binary(0x6)
        assert int(binary) == 6
      E TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Binary'

    def test_binary_init_binstr():
        binary = Binary('0b110')
        assert int(binary) == 6
     E  TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Binary'
```

I don't understand this error. What am I doing wrong?

edit: heres the class produced by the blog author:

```
import collections

class Binary:
    def __init__(self, value=0):
        if isinstance(value, collections.Sequence):
            if len(value) > 2 and value[0:2] == '0b':
                self._value = int(value, base=2)
            elif len(value) > 2 and value[0:2] == '0x':
                self._value = int(value, base=16)
            else:
                self._value = int(''.join([str(i) for i in value]), base=2)
        else:
            try:
                self._value = int(value)
                if self._value < 0:
                    raise ValueError("Binary cannot accept negative numbers. Use SizedBinary instead")
            except ValueError:
                raise ValueError("Cannot convert value {} to Binary".format(value))

    def __int__(self):
        return self._value
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `int` function cannot deal with user defined classes unless you specify in the class how it should work.  The `__int__`  (not init) function gives the built-in python `int()` function information regarding how your user defined class (in this case, Binary) should be converted to an int.

```
class Binary:
    ...your init here
    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.value) #assuming self.value is of type int
```

Then you should be able to do things like.

```
print int(Binary(0x3)) #should print 3
```

I might also suggest standardizing the input for the `__init__` function and the value of `self.value`.  Currently, it  can accept either a string (e.g `'0b011'` or a `0x3`) or an int.  Why not just always make it accept a string as input and always keep self.value as an int.

Comment: Hi Garrett, thanks for answering. I'm a beginner so sorry for not understanding . I've read through https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int . 1. Regarding "The int function cannot deal with user defined classes unless you specify in the class how it should work." The class developed by the blog author does not do this, unless I am misunderstanding (Please see edit above). 2. regarding  "Why not just always make it accept a string as input " - How do you do this?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help. 2 questions: 1) is the Binary class's `__int__` function overriding the builtin int()  2. regarding "Why not just always make it accept a string as input " - How do you do this?