# TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'

Tags: python, oop

I'm working through this [tutorial](http://blog.thedigitalcatonline.com/blog/2015/05/13/python-oop-tdd-example-part1/#.VxEEfjE2sdQ). I'm working through this iteratively. At this point I have the following Binary class:

```
class Binary:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = str(value)
        if self.value[:2] == '0b':
            print('a binary!')
            self.value= int(self.value, base=2)
        elif self.value[:2] == '0x':
            print('a hex!')
            self.value= int(self.value, base=16)
        else:
            print(self.value)
        return int(self.value)
```

I'm running through a suite of tests using pytest, including:

```
    def test_binary_init_hex():
        binary = Binary(0x6)
        assert int(binary) == 6
      E TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Binary'
```

I asked a question about this [TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Binary'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652639/typeerror-int-argument-must-be-a-string-or-a-number-not-binary) and based on the answer changed the code to as above. Now when I run the suite of tests using pytest, all the tests fail and the error is:

```
       TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'int'
```

Why is there a problem?

---

<sub>Fundamentally, the problem in this question was caused by a typo: writing `__init__` where `__int__` should have been used instead. However, it resulted in an interesting and worthy question specifically about what happened as a result of the typo.</sub>

<sub>See [Why isn't my class initialized by "def __int__" or "def _init_"? Why do I get a "takes no arguments" TypeError, or an AttributeError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72482298) for the opposite problem - writing `__int__` where `__init__` should be used instead.</sub>

Comment: That answer doesn't return `int` from `__init__`. It defines an `__int__` method, used for numeric conversion.

Comment: `__init__()` is used to initialize objects, so do not use it that way but use a separate method for this later purpose.

Comment: Why is this even a class and not just a function?

Answer (score 22):

Before any answer was provided, I commented you that `__init__()` is used to initialize objects and thus you must not return any value within it. But it is strange to see some of the upvoted answers above asked not to return values within `__init__()` but still their solution does not respect what they said. Only [*@CPanda*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6153562/c-panda) did not do the opposite of what he said. That is why I want to [highlight this again](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__) as answer:

> Called after the instance has been created (by `__new__()`), but before
>   it is returned to the caller. The arguments are those passed to the
>   class constructor expression. If a base class has an `__init__()`
>   method, the derived class's `__init__()` method, if any, must explicitly
>   call it to ensure proper initialization of the base class part of the
>   instance; for example: `BaseClass.__init__(self, [args...]).`
>
> Because `__new__()` and `__init__()` work together in constructing objects (**new**() to create it, and `__init__()` to customise it), no
>   non-None value may be returned by `__init__()`; doing so will cause a
>   `TypeError` to be raised at runtime.

**So do NOT return values using `__init__()`!**

An other thing I want to add, even if this is not mentioned AFAIK in **[*Python Enhancement Proposals*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/)**, I personally never use `__init__()` to print messages using `print''`/`print('')`. The only messages I print in  `__init__()` are those related to raised exception error messages in a forms such as [`raise ValueError()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) (check [*Built-in Exceptions*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html) for more information)

Answer (score 9):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__init__#object.__init__) states:

"*Because `__new__()` and `__init__()` work together in constructing objects (`__new__()` to create it, and `__init__()` to customise it), no non-None value may be returned by `__init__()`; doing so will cause a TypeError to be raised at runtime.*"

So remove that `return` statement and place it in an `__int__` method in your class:

```
def __int__(self):
    return int(self.value)
```

Comment: Why do you return an int when you say that it should not be done? This is confusing.

Comment: @MartinThoma: are you confusing `__int__` with `__init__` perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

`__init__` Cannot return anything other than `None`. This is because it is the initialiser of an instance created by `__new__`, both of which are called implicitly when you call the class callable. Hence if you try to return anything yourself from it, a `TypeError` exception is raised.

Possible solutions are refactor your code in to methods or `@property`s and use them later. If you want something more daring checkout metaclasses.

Answer (score 4):

`__init__` initializes an instance of a class (in your case, an instance of `Binary`). An instance of a class is a specific *thing* of a specific *type*.

In your case, you seem to be not using it as a *type* of *thing* but instead as a utility that intelligently converts numbers. You should instead probably just make it a function:

```
def binary ( value ) :
    value = str(value)
    if self.value[:2] == '0b':
        print('a binary!')
        value = int(value, base=2)
    elif self.value[:2] == '0x':
        print('a hex!')
        value = int(value, base=16)
    else:
        print(value)
    return int(value)
```

Comment: Thank you, you are probably right, but I'm following the blog post to teach myself some oop

Comment: But you are missing the point of OOP because what you're making isn't an object.

Answer (score 2):

`__init__` is called, after a instance was created with

```
obj = SomeClass()
```

So there is now way to assign any return value to a variable, therefore `__init__` must not return anything (except implicitly `None`).

To pass your test, the object should have a magic method `__int__`, which is called, when the function `int` is used.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that answered another question I had , which is what is the `__int__` method? So if I understand correctly `__int__` is overriding the regular int() built in function?