# How can I add a pane to nuke and use it inside the GUI?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2, qtwidgets, nuke

I am trying to create a nuke pane that I can call the same way the embedded panes are called.
So far, I am able to see it in the 'custom windows' menu, but when I press on the button, the panel shows up empty.

[image]

I know the code is working because when I copy/paste it in the script editor, it works as desired, but I am probably missing some function that calls for my pane to be populated.

I am using QtWidgets, and this is my reduced code:

```
class NukePanel_AssetManager(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        myTable    = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        # all my functions and the things I am creating #
        self.layout().addWidget(myTable)

pane = nuke.getPaneFor('Properties.1')
panels.registerWidgetAsPanel('NukePanel_AssetManager', 'Asset Manager', 'uk.co.thefoundry.NukePanel_AssetManager', True).addToPane(pane)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it!!

```
import nukescripts
import myPanelScript


pathToClass='myPanelScript.NukePanel_AssetManager' #the full python path to your panel
HRName='Asset Manager' #the Human-readable name you want for your panel
regName='NukePanel.AssetManager' #the internal registered name for this panel (used for saving and loading layouts)

nukescripts.panels.registerWidgetAsPanel(pathToClass, HRName, regName, True).addToPane(nuke.getPaneFor('Properties.1'))
```

Thank you all for your answers, as this would have not been possible for me without your inputs!!

Answer (score 1):

It probably has to do with where the panel is being defined. Since the first argument in `registerWidgetAsPanel` is a string-representation of the name of the panel class (so weird), it works in the script panel (because it is defined right there), but not when you're loading it via init (because it is actually being defined in your module). If your module is named `MyPanels`:

```
from nukescripts.panels import registerWidgetAsPanel

pathToClass='MyPanels.NukePanel_AssetManager' #the full python path to your panel
HRName='Asset Manager' #the Human-readable name you want for your panel
regName='NukePanel.AssetManager' #the internal registered name for this panel (used for saving and loading layouts)

registerWidgetAsPanel(pathToClass, HRName, regName)
```

Nuke has some some strange and inconsistent module importing; if you still have trouble, try adding your panel/module as a variable under the nuke module, which is available everywhere:

```
import nuke
from MyPanels import NukePanel_AssetManager

nuke.NukePanel_AssetManager=NukePanel_AssetManager
```

Hacky, but has helped me out a lot in the past!

Comment: Thanks, I tried with your first code in menu.py and modified it a bit:

`code`

registerWidgetAsPanel(pathToClass, HRName, regName, True).addToPane(nuke.getPaneFor('Properties.1'))
`code`

But I still don't get it populated. The buttons are all there, but I should also see my read nodes in a table, which is not showing. Any idea?

Comment: hmmm that sounds like a seperate QT issue! If your panel shows up where it should be, then we're probably past this code.

Answer (score 0):

## Modal pane

The simplest way to have a regular modal pane in Nuke GUI is the following one:

```
import nuke

pane = nuke.Panel('Set number of Blur nodes')
pane.addSingleLineInput('Number of Blur nodes', '')
pane.show()

someInput = pane.value('Number of Blur nodes')

if someInput <= "0": 
    nuke.message('ERROR\nSet a number between 1 and 3')
elif someInput >= "4":
    nuke.message('ERROR\nSet a number between 1 and 3')
elif "1" <= someInput <= "3":
    nuke.message('number of Blur nodes: ' + someInput)
    
    for _ in list(range(1, int(someInput[0]) + 1)):
        nuke.createNode('Blur', inpanel = False)
```

## Non-modal pane

Of course, you often want a non-modal panes, like depicted on a picture:

[image]

```
import nuke
import nukescripts

class Panes:

    def createPane(self):
        pythonPanel = nukescripts.PythonPanel('Keying Panel')
        knob = nuke.Keyer_Knob('keyer', 'range')
        knob.setValue( [0.0, 0.075, 0.5, 1.0] )
        pythonPanel.addKnob(knob)
        pythonPanel.addToPane()
        return self

Panes().createPane()
```

Comment: Thank you Andy, but this code creates a pop-up pane in a new window. But I need my pane to be embedded in the GUI like any other pane (such as node graph, properties, background renders, dope sheet, etc.).

Comment: Hi @Andy. Unvortunately it doesn't. I get this error: TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NukePanel_AssetManager'

Comment: Read this post – https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666353/typeerror-init-should-return-none-not-int/36666552